# Performing a text search and filtering on nested terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to perform a search th e.g. searches the word coyotes in the description , but are red and green and are in the cartoon category. Now I think I understand you can't have match and terms in the same query (the query below doesn't work for this reason), but also you that you shouldn't use terms to search on a text field. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

here's my query

```
GET /searchproducts/_search
{
    "query": {
      "match": {
      "description": {
        "query": "coyote"
      }
    },
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "terms": {
                        "colours.name": ["red", "green"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "categories.name": ["Cartoon"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "colours": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "colour.name.value",
                "size": 100
            }
        },
        "categories": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categories.id",
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine multiple queries. Try out this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "coyote"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "colours.name": [
                    "red",
                    "green"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "categories.name": [
                    "Cartoon"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "colours": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "colour.name.value",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.id",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: pretty sure we should use `filter` instead of `should` according to the OP description

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks for the help. I had made a mistake where categories.name needed to be an id. And although your solution worked otherwise, I think @Val suggestion of using filter is correct, so I'm going to go ahead and use that. 

Thanks both! Now to write this in Nest.